# Passing variable along with link defined within map area

Tags: php, html, dictionary, area

I am trying to pass variable along with link. In first page (test.php) I have variable $x that passes to second page (menu.php).

When I send it by normal link, variable got passed to the second page without an issue. But when same was passed with the link defined within map area tags, only the first instance of the variable got passed always. (Always print 0)

Could somebody help me?

test.php

```
 <?php
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    ?>
    <p>
    <img src="uploads\network.png" width="1261" height="961" usemap="#planetmap">
    <?php echo $x ; ?>
    <map name="planetmap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="91,31,211,151" alt="Sun" href="menu.php?projectid=<?php echo $x;?>" target="_blank">

    </map>
    </p>

    <a href="menu.php?projectid=<?php echo $x;?>">link</a>
    <?php

    }       
    ?>
```

menu.php

```
 <?php
   $cell = $_GET["projectid"];
   echo $cell;   
   ?>
```

Actual HTML (View source)

```
<img src="uploads\network.png" width="1261" height="961" usemap="#planetmap">
0<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="91,31,211,151" alt="Sun" href="menu.php?projectid=0" target="_blank">

</map>
</p>

<a href="menu.php?projectid=0">link</a>

<img src="uploads\network.png" width="1261" height="961" usemap="#planetmap">
1<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="91,31,211,151" alt="Sun" href="menu.php?projectid=1" target="_blank">

</map>
</p>

<a href="menu.php?projectid=1">link</a>

<img src="uploads\network.png" width="1261" height="961" usemap="#planetmap">
2<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="91,31,211,151" alt="Sun" href="menu.php?projectid=2" target="_blank">

</map>
</p>

<a href="menu.php?projectid=2">link</a>
```

Comment: What does the actual HTML output look like, not the PHP source?

Comment: I added first page 'view source' HTML to original post. thanks. view source of menu.php doesn't show anything.

Comment: You have closing `</p>` tags in your loop without an opening `<p>`

Comment: Found the answer. map name must be unique in each iteration of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you will just want to have the in the file you are linking too`$projectid = $_GET['projectid'];`